# Timer failing to trigger in very specific circumstances

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I'm trying to use a `System.Threading.Timer` to exit a program after a certain number of seconds, and it's failing in specific circumstances. I've boiled it down to a minimum test case.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

class test {
    static void SetTimer() {
        new Timer(a => Environment.Exit(0), null, 1000L, 0L);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        SetTimer();
        for (;;) {
            var v = new List<int>();
        }
    }
}
```

The above program should exit after one second, but it just hangs indefinitely.

But every part of the above code is necessary. The timer has to be set in a separate function; if it is set directly in Main, the program exits after one second. The infinite loop has to be doing something nontrivial; if it just increments an integer variable, the program exits after one second.

It's not the C# compiler per se at fault; the equivalent code in F# behaves the same way.

This is with Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10, and `csc -version` is `4.1.0-5.22109.6 (0c82c411)`.

Is this a .Net bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: *am I doing something wrong?* tight loop on a nonop? Await a delay instead; your CPU has better things to do I'm sure..

Comment: @CaiusJard It's a minimum test case. Obviously the real program is doing useful work in the main loop, but you wouldn't thank me for posting several thousand lines of code to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your new Timer is already gone before the callback is executed. You should add a static Timer timer in the class that retains the object so it can keep executing. Here's my answer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

class test
{
    static Timer timer;
    static void SetTimer()
    {
        timer = new Timer(a =>
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);

        }, null, 1000L, 1000L);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetTimer();

        for (; ; )
        {
            var v = new List<int>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks! What really threw me off was the way the problem disappears if the subsequent loop is simple enough, but maybe there is an explanation for that... Maybe the optimizer in the JIT compiler was able to figure out that a sufficiently simple subsequent loop wasn't doing anything, and therefore that there was no need to return to it, so in that case the set timer function never returned.

Comment: No, as I said. The Timer is gone as soon als the SetTimer() method is finished. The GC will clean up after that. The callback will probably never be executed.